# How to update DOM with value returned from Axios?

Tags: vue.js

I need to loop through the elements with the **ticket** class, pass his name to an *API* and update the next element (loading) with the *API's* return.

The problem is that I have no way to access the API return outside *axios*, and if I try to update the element inside *axios*, i don't have access to **tickets[index]**.

Should I be making this call differently?

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td class="ticket">T1</td>
   <td>loading</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="ticket">T2</td>
   <td>loading</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
    const tickets = document.getElementsByClassName('ticket')
    let price = null

    for (let index = 0; index < tickets.length; index++) {
        axios
            .get('/api/prices/' + tickets[index].innerText)
            .then(response => {
                price = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

        tickets[index].nextElementSibling.textContent = price
    }
```

Comment: It won't work like that because the loop is sync. This requires to chain promises correctly. Use async/await

Comment: I used what you said and it worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using the methods that the
Estus Flask mentioned (**async/await**).

If anyone has the same problem, here is the complete code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {

      }
    },
    async mounted () {
        const tickets = document.getElementsByClassName('ticket')

        for (let index = 0; index < tickets.length; index++) {
            await axios
                .get('/api/prices/' + tickets[index].innerText)
                .then(response => {
                    tickets[index].nextElementSibling.textContent = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It will probably be better to use vue's state instead of interacting directly with the DOM

Comment: How could i do that since there are multiple values? Can you give me an example of what it would look like?

Comment: Yes, check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-violet-y57rgs?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue (you might need to toggle the preview twice, since sometimes it gives a weird error related to imports)